# Current Location não funciona com MapModule

Tags: javascript, ios

Utilizando o Appcelerator, iniciando um novo projeto e preciso colocar minha localização atual no mapa, porém não consigo coloca-lo. Só consigo colocar um ponto fixo. Segue meus códigos abaixo:

***/Resources/ui/controller/geolocation.js:***

```
var points = [];
Titanium.Geolocation.accuracy = Titanium.Geolocation.ACCURACY_BEST;

Titanium.Geolocation.distanceFilter = 10;

Titanium.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(e){
activityScreen.show();

if (e.error)
{
    alert('HFL cannot get your current location');
    activityScreen.hide();
    return;
}

win.longitude   = e.coords.longitude;
win.latitude    = e.coords.latitude;

win.latitude    = -23.4438148;
win.longitude   = -46.5335198;

if(typeof(vc) != "undefined")
{
    vc.latitude     = win.latitude; 
    vc.longitude    = win.longitude;

    mapview.region = {
        latitude:win.latitude, longitude: win.longitude,
        latitudeDelta:0.1, longitudeDelta:0.1
    };

}

activityScreen.hide();

});
```

***/Resources/ui/view/iphone/mapa/maps.js:***

```
Ti.include("/ui/controller/geolocation.js");
var MapModule = require('ti.map');


var vc = MapModule.createAnnotation({
 latitude: win.latitude,
 longitude: win.longitude,
 title: 'Você está aqui',
 subtitle: 'São Paulo, SP',
 pincolor: MapModule.ANNOTATION_GREEN,
 image:"/ui/images/zapsacmini.png",
});

var walmart = MapModule.createAnnotation({
 latitude: -23.474891,
 longitude: -46.526756,
 title: 'Loja',
 subtitle: 'Guarulhos, SP',
 pincolor: MapModule.ANNOTATION_RED,
 image:"/ui/images/loja.png",
}); 


var mapview = MapModule.createView({
top:0,
height: "80%",
mapType: MapModule.NORMAL_TYPE,
region: {latitude: win.latitude, longitude: win.longitude, latitudeDelta: 0.001, longitudeDelta: 0.001},
annotations: [vc,walmart],
animate:true,
});

mapview.visible = false;

win.add(mapview);
```

Quando testo minha aplicação, apenas aparece o ponto fixo (Loja).
Somente não aparece o meu *Current Location*!

Lembrando que já coloquei as ***key*** NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription e NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription no meu ***tiapp.xml***

alguém sabe qual o problema disso ou código correto?